# Show that if a prime number $p|a^n$ then $p|a$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

The title says it all, how can I prove the following:

> Show that if a prime number $p|a^n$ then $p|a$

Comment: What do you already know, Euclid's Lemma, Bezout's GCD Identity, or uniqueness of prime factorizations? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**    $p \mid m \, n \Longrightarrow p \mid m$ or $p \mid n$  for prime $p.$

Answer (score 0):

What it means for $p$ to be prime: For any $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $p|(ab)$, then either $p|a$ or $p|b$. So what can you say if $p|a^2$? How does this help you with your problem?